# Can someone help me add a new column in Google cloud Search Index using Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search, gcloud-java

I tried adding a new column to an existing search index but it is throwing an error, the error as stated below:-
 Field docname is present 0 times; expected 1 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field docname is present 0 times; expected 1

I can see that the new column has been added to the search index but cannot retrieve the index.

By my observation i can see that the existing records in the index dont have the new column data and hence it is giving a this error, but the new records will be having this column values. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Upon having this problem myself today, I searched a bit in the documentation. It was a rather frustrating error as it didn't actually pin point where the problem was in my code.

It appears that when you use `getOnlyField("something")` on a `Document` (in this case on one of many returned from a search query), if that field does not actually exist yet in that specific document it throws the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Because that can often be the case when you update an index with new columns, I'm using something like this to get around it:

```
public static Long getNumberField(ScoredDocument d, String name, Long defaultValue) {
    try {
        return d.getOnlyField(name).getNumber().longValue();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Which is called in the search results code:

```
Long numberValue = SearchUtils.getNumberField(scoredDocument, "featuredOrder", -1L)
```

This allows me to catch that error and return a default value when it doesn't exist.

You can find the documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Document.html#getOnlyField-java.lang.String-